# OpenXML SDK reflected code causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working with a 10-page Microsoft Word document (.docx format) created in Office 2007. I wanted to programmatically create copies of this document in a web server environment (IIS7). So I started by using the OpenXML SDK 2.5 software to reflect the code, then I saved the generated output as a class library which gets deployed with my application. I did not include the reflected code because it is massive (30K lines of code).

My problem is that the unmodified, reflected code from the SDK causes as StackOverflowException and the IIS thread shuts down when I try to create the file. This exception type is more difficult to debug than standard .NET exceptions due to the server running out of memory.

Can anyone suggest reasons why the SDK would be creating code that causes exceptions, or better perhaps, ways that I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the whole file instead of just reusing it?

Comment: Good question. I used this approach because I plan to modify the .docx extensively by passing values and tables of data into the document creator function. The reflected code doesn't even work though, so I cant even begin to modify it.

Comment: The general approach for this is to open your word file programatically using `DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Packaging` and then modify the stuff you need, not to recreate the whole thing with automatically generated (non-efficient) code.

Comment: Opening the document & editing it using a memory stream works just fine - no exceptions occur. Thanks for the suggestion here. I could definitely use this approach, but I am also interested in why the reflected code is crashing.